# Issue with Interactivity in MVVMLight

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

Everyone, I am working on an MVVMLight app with WPF but my problem is that I want to fire the `Loaded` event once the user can load the page. For e.g. I have some navigation pages, so whenever the user clicks on any page, the `PageLoaded` event should be fired. But in my case it is not fired in the same way. I have a another page that's working perfectly fine. I don't know where I am making a mistake .

My Xaml code looks like this:

> ```
>     xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Test.User.Facebook.ViewModel"
> <UserControl.Resources>
>     <ResourceDictionary>
>        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"/>
>      </ResourceDictionary>
> </UserControl.Resources>
>
>
> <UserControl.DataContext>
>     <Binding Source="{StaticResource Locator}" Path="FriendsList"/>
> </UserControl.DataContext>
>
>
> <i:Interaction.Triggers>
>     <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
>         <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" />
>     </i:EventTrigger>
> </i:Interaction.Triggers>
> ```

And the ViewModel looks like this :

```
public RelayCommand LoadedCommand { get; private set; }
public FriendsListViewModel()
{
    LoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(() => UserControlLoaded());
}

private void UserControlLoaded()
{
    GetFriendsList();
}
```

This is not loaded when I go to this page. It doesn't fire the event. Someone can help me?

Thanks..

Comment: Is `EventToCommand` bound to your ViewModel? Maybe you're working on a different `DataContext`. Try setting the `DataContext` explicitly.

Comment: <UserControl.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource Locator}" Path="FacebookMainMenu"/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

Comment: I had tested with above approach..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the loaded event occurs before the interaction is stared. Therefore, EventToCommand cannot be used to handle the load event. In this case I usually create an event handler, that obtains the command from the DataContext. Then the CanExecute method of the command is evaluated and if it returns true the Execute method is called.

This pattern des not contradict the MVVM pattern and is a clean way out of the occasions when EventToCommand cannot be used. One drawback, however, is hat the CanExecute status is not bound to the enabled property automaticall. But this should not be a problem for the rare ocasions where you have to use this pattern, as when you have no interaction you usually don't have a visual.

Comment: Thanks @Obalix but this is not possible in our case...! but once again thanks for giving good idea..!

Comment: @Jitendra_Jadav: Why is it not possible? As I said it is a common way to circumnavigate the case when events cannot be handled by the EventToCommand mechanism (there are oher events too). It des not brake the MVVM pattern as it still separates the VM code from the view and the code is only related to the view. S please share your constraints so hat the communit has a chance of finding the right answer.

Comment: @Jitendra_Jadav: ... do you need a sample?

Comment: yes then definetly I can check out this approach is possible in our case.!